# Create Excel with Drop down using Open XML

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am creating an excel with drop down values using Open XML (DocumentFormat.OpenXML). There are no errors in the code and excel gets created. But I get couple of errors while opening the excel. Excel gets opened with data correctly if I click OK to the errors and go ahead.  It looks like the problem is due to the addition of namespace in order to have the dropdown values.

Question is, Is there any way to get rid of the error?

Error 1:

> We found a problem with some content in 'sample.xlsx'. Do you want us
>   to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this
>   workbook, click Yes.

Error 2:

> Errors were detected in file 'Sample.xlsx'
>    Repaired Records: Cell information
>   from /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml part
>   Repaired Records: Cell information from
>   /xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml part

C# Namespace addition for creating excel:

```
worksheet1 = new Worksheet() { MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes() { Ignorable = "x14ac" } };
worksheet1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("x14ac", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac");
```

Comment: `It looks like the problem is due to the addition of namespace in order to have the dropdown values.` What brought you to that conclusion?

Comment: this is my assumption because creating an excel without dropdown values and omitting this namespace line works without issues.

Comment: There could be many reasons for this error. Can you share your code? How do you insert your data, is there any styling applied? And how do you validate your dropdown?

Comment: Hello, Please find my sample application here in github https://github.com/KarthickTC/OpenXMLExcelProject